# Techniques or tools to faciltate work in 2 o more versions of a same software

Tags: wordpress, version-control, netbeans

I just finishing working in a Wordpress plugin. This plugin is split in 2 versions (standard and premium). The difficult start when I have to solve bugs that are common to both versions.
Currently I proceed like this:
Unpack one version to the Wordpress plugin dir, debug, pack again.
And then the same for the another version.
Not so painful but what really should be ideal is work only over one code and then send the changes to both versions at the same time. More over: automatically zipping and sending by email through a bash script or similar should be the heaven on Earth.
I use Linux and Netbeans (can manage git, mercurial and subversion) but no need to be involved in the solution.
THX.-

Comment: Why close? This question is SO related. FAQ says: `software tools commonly used by programmers`

Comment: Close reason: "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form."

Answer (score 0):

> More over: automatically zipping and sending by email

Zipping **what**? Sending **where**?

At least sending is dependent from "other" side, which have to handle it

Without describing more detailed used workflow I can't see ways to answer on question. Are both versions related by code (i.e Premium is **patches on top** of Standard /or vice versa/)? Do you use any SCM now? Do you use branches? Can you use hooks in VCS-of-choice?

Comment: I am talking about WP plugins. So `zipping` plugin, `sending` to client. So the workflow is related to `Wordpress Plugin Development`. I said clearly.

Comment: @NomikOS - I can read written text. Fist you sentence is obviously MISS. Second - unclear. Other questions still not answered: I'm afraid, **you don't want to get answers**, and just steal time

Comment: I saw in your profile that you have quite experience on versioning and it would be very helpful but you have a very bad attitude so please forget it. And sorry for lost your time. I also answer questions here and I do it to contribute, nobody is required to answer. And please stop yell with your bold words.